Log4J doesn't write to file in native Os X application
I'm using Log4J (v2.x) to write statements to a log file. All works well during debugging, but after compiling it as a native Os X app (using jPackage), the app no longer writes statements to the log file. Only an empty log file is created.
Does anyone have any idea's?
log4j2.properties file located in the resources folder ...
appender.file.type=RollingFile
appender.file.name=File
appender.file.filePattern=${logFile}.%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.gz
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=%d{dd:MM:yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %-5level| %logger{36} - %msg%n
appender.file.policies.type=Policies
appender.file.policies.time.type=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy

# Root Logger
rootLogger.level=debug
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.ref=File
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.level=debug
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.filters.type=ThresholdFilter
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.filters.level=debug
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.filters.onMatch=ACCEPT
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.filters.onMismatch=DENY
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.if=${sys:enableLogging} 

Main.java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.*;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.BuiltConfiguration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

...

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    setLoggerFilePath("<PATH TO LOG FILE>");

    // Do other stuff
}

private static void setLoggerFilePath(String _filePath){
    LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.setStatusLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    builder.setConfigurationName("ProgrammaticConfig");

    // Define the layout pattern
    LayoutComponentBuilder layoutBuilder = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout");
    layoutBuilder.addAttribute("pattern", "%d{dd:MM:yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %-5level| %logger{36} - %msg%n");

    // Define the file appender with a file path
    AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("File", "File");
    appenderBuilder.addAttribute("fileName", _filePath);
    appenderBuilder.add(layoutBuilder);

    // Add the appender to the configuration
    builder.add(appenderBuilder);

    // Set root logger level and add appender
    builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.DEBUG).add(builder.newAppenderRef("File")));

    // Build the configuration
    Configuration config = builder.build();

    // Initialize the LoggerContext with the Configuration
    LoggerContext contextNew = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    contextNew.start(config);

    Configurator.initialize(config);

    logger.debug("Application started ...");

}


Where are you executing the native application?
